# Autofac - does lifetime scope use root scope instance if it exists?

Tags: autofac

This is likely a noob question.

Suppose I need to resolve some interface say IFunctional in web request processing which is registered as instance per lifetime scope in autofac configuration. But before I do it, I have already resolved IService which is registered as single instance and also has dependency on IFunctional. Therefore IService has already been resolved in root scope and IFunctional has already been resolved in root scope as well. Now trying to resolve IFunctional in say, web request processing, will it:

1. create new instance of IFunctional in "web request scope"
2. look for an instance of IFunctional in tree of scopes and find one in root scope and use that one?

To me the first option makes more sense, but I would rather be sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your stuation:
IService (singleton) has IFunctional(per lifetime). So this IFunctional object will live with IService. But other classes will not use this IFunctional. In short: This IFunctional will be just used by IService.

When request starts, also new request lifetime scope starts. So when you tried to resolve/get IFunctional object in this scope, it checks *are there any IFunctional object in my scope ?*. If there is not, it creates new one. Otherwise it uses IFunctional which is in this scope, not in other scopes even in root one (Because IFunctional is not singleton).

Therefore, **The first option** will take place.

Comment: Thanks for a fast answer! This destroys my insecurities :)

Comment: I don't suggest you to use per lifetime in singletons. It can break your design. Additionaly it can be very dangerous, if they are disposable. Because _per lifetime_ in word you expect it starts and ends. Use factories or follow SRP. May be IService doesn't need IFunctional at all may be it just need some parts which can be singleton or per dependent.

Comment: Not quite getting that part. Are you pointing out that using per lifetime dependency in single instance object may be dangerous because that per lifetime object will actually live as long as the single instance? And if there is a bound resource it will be held for the whole program life? Let's say logging service (singleton) needs transaction service (per lifetime) to write to DB. Doesn't seem that dangerous to me. If you do lot of logging, it could be inefficient to go per dependent way. It seems OK from SRP point of view too, since I believe SRP is referring to classes not instances.